# Can it be over fitting when validation loss and validation accuracy is both increasing?

Tags: classification, neural-networks, overfitting, sparse

Training a simple neural network over a very sparse matrix (Has 2400 features and 18000 train rows) for a binary classification problem. At the end of 1st epoch validation loss started to increase, whereas validation accuracy is also increasing. Can i call this over fitting? I'm thinking of stopping the training after 6th epoch. My criteria would be: stop if the accuracy is decreasing. Is there something really wrong going on?

ps: I have perfectly balanced binary classification dataset and a random classifier would result around %50 accuracy.

[image: Getting this figure]

Comment: Based on the second graph you would say that your model is overfitting, since a similar increase in accuracy from the training set does not happen on the test set.

Comment: Yes but the accuracy is increasing a bit, even to the %65 accuracy level.. If i stop my network when validation loss is increasing i get %55 accuracy. Wouldn't it be better to have %65 accurate network over %55? I am questioning the stopping criteria.

Comment: I would say from epoch 3 forward the increase is marginal. Maybe this validation loss criterion is not the best in your case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. First of all, overfitting is best judged by looking at loss, rather than accuracy, for a series of reasons including the fact that accuracy is not a good way to estimate the performance of classification models. See here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/58675

[Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312780/why-is-accuracy-not-the-best-measure-for-assessing-classification-models)

[Classification probability threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312119/classification-probability-threshold/312124#312124)

Secondly, even if you use accuracy, rather than loss, to judge overfitting (and you shouldn't), you can't just look at the (smoothed) derivative of accuracy on the test curve, i.e., if it's increasing on average or not. You should first of all look at the **gap**  between training accuracy and test accuracy. And in your case this gap is very large: you'd better use a scale which starts either at 0, or at the accuracy of the random classifier (i.e., the classifiers which assigns each instance to the majority class), but even with your scale, we're talking a training accuracy of nearly 100%, vs. a test accuracy which doesn't even get to 65%.

TL;DR: you don't want to hear it, but your model is as overfit as they get.

PS: you're focusing on the **wrong** problem. The issue here is not whether to do early stopping at the 1th epoch for a test accuracy of 55%, or whether to stop at epoch 7 for an accuracy of 65%. The real issue here is that your training accuracy (but again, I would focus on the test loss) is way too high with respect to your test accuracy. 55%, 65% or even 75% are all **crap** with respect to 99%. This is a textbook case of overfitting. You need to do something about it, not focus on the "less worse" epoch for early stopping.

Comment: What would be the best way to approach to the problem i have tried noises, dropouts etc? I wouldn't expect a better test accuracy then %65 for this dataset. Should i be preventing the network to get a high train accuracy? Or should i prevent the gap to be widen a lot?

Comment: as a side note: I have perfectly balanced binary classification dataset.

Comment: it's impossible to answer if you don't a) describe in detail what's your problem, b) explain the why you don't expect a better than 65% test accuracy for this dataset. Of  course "I have a hunch that test accuracy can't better than 65%" is **not** a valid reason, while "I have extensive bibliographic evidence that SOTA on this dataset, or on a _extremely similar_ one, cannot exceed 65%" is a valid reason. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/363895/58675 for some references on SOTA results for different ML problems (alas, mostly NLP and CV). And btw, note that how to reduce the test error 1/

Comment: 2/ on your problem is a completely different question from what you asked. You need to ask a new question and describe your actual dataset & model much more in detail, as well as describe extensively all the things you have already tried. For your own sanity, I hope you're not using Jupyter notebooks to keep track of this kind of extensive numerical experiments.

Comment: @DeltaIV interesting, what do you suggest using instead of Jupyter notebooks to track this kind of experiments? That's a serious question as I've been doing exactly that lately and starting to feel this pain.

Comment: @Jivan comments are not for extended discussion or question answering. Check which SE site would be more appropriate for such a question and ask there. I don't think CV is the right place to ask about tools to track deep learning numerical experiments....you may still ask on Meta    to get a second opinion though.

Comment: @DeltaIV well I was just hoping that you'd throw a couple/handful of words here in order to get on the right track, nothing elaborate or extended

Answer (score 0):

There is at least two possible cause to this curve variation in this case that can happen. The reasonable possible distinctions that we can assume by looking at this graphical dataset, is as follow :

1- This training network indicate validation loss because the model is overfitting.

This answer here could be is a personal review by myself while studying this subject, and having hard time to come over the conclusion. There is many answer here, but the ideal choice would be the number 1 answer that i have mentioned.

2- Other possible cause would be that this training network have unknown variante or error in the trained dataset, like a spontaneous reaction for example.

Feel free to comment.